# NSTextField Focus

Tags: swift, nstextfield

How to remove focus on NSTextField if I'm not focus in the textField?

I have a NSTextField and I set the Action: Sent On End Editing. After clicking the textField, the FOCUS will always in my NSTextField when I click other places on the view. 
Furthermore, I use **makeFirstResponder** and **resignFirstResponder** but all in vain. Any idea?

```
@IBAction func endOfEditing(sender: NSTextField) {
    view.window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    view.window?.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

For illustration, the FOCUS will always be in textField no matter where I pressed. (Even when I pressed the button)

[image]

How can I remove the focus when I click outside the textField?

[image]

Comment: I personally do not know much a about Swift, however it might be because you're using `view.window?`. You might want to try using the name of your ViewController class, however once again I am very new to Swift. Also, I'm not too sure if I understand your question correctly. Maybe clarify how you want the NSTextField to be focused, what that means exactly?

Comment: You should do `resignFirstResponder()` on your text view

Comment: @Lee I've tried `sender.window?.resignFirstResponder()` but in vain ..

Comment: `sender.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: @LeoDabus  not working as well

Answer (score 3):

Just try this: change "view.window?" to "sender"

```
@IBAction func endOfEditing(sender: NSTextField) {
   sender.makeFirstResponder(nil)
   sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: makeFirstResponder is a method of NSWindow, NSTextField doesn't have such one

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419366-makefirstresponder

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

For those still troubling with focus and unfocus: I don't know if it was the case back in 2016, but in Swift 4 my `NSTextField` loses focus except if I click in another "selectable" outlet.

For instance if I click on a `NSButton` right after `NSTextField` it won't lost focus. I suspect the `NSButton` catches the event, preventing the textfield to know it has to unfocus.

Here is a much radical solution which will definitely defocus an `NSTextField`

```
@IBAction func clickMyButton(_ sender: NSButton) { // or anywhere else

    self.quantityTextField.isEnabled = false
    self.quantityTextField.isEnabled = true

}
```

Not very sexy but it is reliable

*Edit: Just saw it, it solves @Lee's issue*

Comment: Rather than disabling and re-enabling the field, you can use `self.yourTextField.abortEditing()`

Answer (score 0):

try add this function to your viewController

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // I assume your textField call myText
    myText. resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: `override func mouseDown(event: NSEvent) {
        NSApp.mainWindow!.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    }` works when click on the view. However, It didn't work if I click on the button. By doing so, I must have to makeFirstResponder everywhere on my view controller? Any better idea?

Comment: @WeiJay I nvr used mouseDown before, but I just thinking resignFirstResponder when touch on view is ok, and if you want button click you can go ahead and do that with same code and function when ur button clicked.

Comment: But just think in logic, there is not that logic if you have a lot of button or other elements on your one screen, not really good for User Experience. Although im not really sure what you are going to do, but do it one by one, don't think too complicated first.